# Is it ever "ok" to use multiple queries instead of one?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

In building a web app recently, I started thinking about the information returned from a query I was making:

Find the user information and (for simplicity sake) the associated phone numbers tied to this user. Something as simple as:

```
SELECT a.fname, a.lname, b.phone 
FROM users a 
JOIN users_phones b 
    ON (a.userid = b.userid) 
WHERE a.userid = 12345;
```

No problem here (yes I'm preventing injection, etc, not the point of this question). When I think about the data that is returned though, I am returning (potentially) several rows of information with that users name on each one. Let's say that single user has 1000 phone numbers associated with it. That's a first name and last name being returned each call a lot. Let's also assume I want to return a lot more than just the first name and last name of that user and in fact I'm starting to return quite a bit of extra rows which I really only needed once.

Are there circumstances in which it is "more appropriate" to make multiple calls to a database?

e.g.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname 
FROM users 
WHERE userid = 12345;

SELECT phone 
FROM users_phones 
WHERE userid = 12345;
```

If the answer is yes, is there a good/proper method of determining when to use multiple queries versus a single one?

Comment: I would just make it a subquery and return just the phone numbers, wrap it in SELECT phone FROM (......)

Comment: AFAIC, Step 1: write the query correctly. Doesn't matter if you do 1 database query or 1000, as long as it's correct. Step 2: Your application might be slow. Make the parts that are slow faster (but only if you have a reasonable definition of "slow". "Slow" doesn't mean "something that could be faster", but "something that is actually causing a problem from taking too long").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query with a `JOIN` may be slower than two independent queries. It really depends on the type of access you're doing.

For your example, I'd go with the two query approach. These queries could be executed in parallel, they could be cached, and there's no real reason to `JOIN` other than for arbitrary presentation concerns.

You'll also want to be concerned about returning duplicate data. In your example it looks like `fname` and `lname` would be repeated for each and every phone number, resulting in a lot of data being transmitted that's actually not useful. This is because of the *one-to-many* relationship you've described.

Generally you'll want to `JOIN` if it means sending less data, or because the two queries are not independent.

Answer (score 3):

I think that really depends on your use case.  In the example you gave, it seems to make sense to return it as two queries, especially if you're passing that info back to a mobile device where you want to make sure you send them as little data as possible (not everyone has unlimited data.....)

I'd probably stick a DISTINCT in those queries as well if that's going to make a difference based on your tables.

Answer (score 0):

This should be driven by the application. Basically, you retrieve in one query all the information needed in one place. If you take this question page as an example, you see your user ID, the reputation counter, and the badge counters. There's no need to retrieve other user profile information when I first display the question page.

Only when one clicks on the user ID the rest of the profile may be queried, and may be not even all of it, as there are several tabs on the profile page.

However, if your application is guaranteed to access all 1000 phone numbers at once, along with the user's name, then you probably should fetch them all together.

Comment: unless I am not reading you correctly, I would still access all the information I need in the same "page" - it would just be in 1 call or 2 (or more). In your example, you are assuming the information isn't being displayed on the same page (it is). The issue is returning fname and lname 1000 times just because that user has 1000 phone numbers

Comment: I'm not sure what your concern is. I had a feeling that you somehow reluctant to use joins. You shouldn't be. Only if you are worried about the the extra network traffic or the memory usage to keep all these redundant names, then you may have a reason to not use the join.

Comment: My concern is returning extra unnecessary information and what determining factors should indicate in an app when to use multiple queries instead of a single one with a join. You are essentially just reiterating what I have already asked. I am not "reluctant" to use joins. I use them all the time in various applications when necessary. Your last comment essentially tells me you don't understand the question since it is just restating my issue.

Comment: Well, may be you don't understand my answer then.

Comment: I do understand it. I believe it to be incorrect personally and given the 0 votes here and up-votes on answers that basically say the opposite of your last line. "driven by the application" is true and I understand that. Thank you for your answer either way.